# The sum of exponentials compared to their average

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone please help me prove/disprove the following equation:
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n e^{f(i)} \geq n\cdot e^{\overline {f(i)}}\\
where\ \forall i \in\{1,...,n\},\  f(i)\in [0,1], \ \ and\ \ \  \overline {f(i)} = \frac1 n \sum\limits_{i=1}^n f(i) $$
I can prove this for n=2, but not for the general case.
Thanks :)

Comment: Let $g(i)=e^{f(i)}$ and divide both sides by $n$.  Then this is equivalent to the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality.  The inequality is not strict (imagine if $f(i)$ is constant)

Comment: @Henry, I forgot the "equal" in "greater or equal" (fixed). Could you please help me understand how a geometric mean is related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformation I suggested of letting $g(i)=e^{f(i)} = \exp(f(i))$ and dividing both sides by $n$,

together with $\displaystyle \exp\left(\overline {f(i)}\right) = \exp\left(\frac1 n \sum f(i)\right) = \sqrt[n]{\exp\left(\sum f(i)\right)}= \sqrt[n]{\prod\exp\left( f(i)\right)}$

leads to you needing to prove $\displaystyle \frac1n \sum g(i) \ge \sqrt[n]{ \prod g(i)}$ which is the [arithmetic-geometric mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

Comment: Great! Thanks for taking the time to explain to a non-mathematician like me :)